# How to extract data from xml with namespace?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Data ("1.0.0") from attribute "version" fall into property. But the property "Event" in the same class remains empty.
If cut namespace from XML, it will work.

My XML:

```
<rootnode>
  <ns:eventresponse xmlns:ns="somenamespace" version="1.0.0">
    <event id="694717028">
      <somedata>val</somedata>
    </event>
  </ns:eventresponse>
</rootnode>
```

My class:

```
[XmlRoot("rootnode")]
public class RootNode
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "eventresponse", Namespace = "somenamespace")]
    public EventResponseData EventResponse { get; set; }
}

  public class EventResponseData
    {
        [XmlElement("event")]
        public EventData Event { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }
    }

public class TvEventData
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string EventID { get; set; } 

    [XmlElement("somedata")]
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

My Deserializer:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
{
     reader.MoveToContent();
     var obj = (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: Please, do not include a languge tag in a title unless it wouldn't made sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `event` element is implicitly in the same namespace in the XML due to namespace defaulting, so you should specify that in your declaration:

```
public class EventResponseData
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "event", Namespace = "somenamespace")]
    public EventData Event { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```